# Xcode - объявление функции

Tags: xcode, объявление

Создал проект, к котором есть два файла cpp.

```
main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"dop.cpp"

int main(){
    f();
}
------------------
dop.cpp
void f(){
    std::cout<<123;
}
```

В принципе он не должен работать, так как у нас нет объявления функции f в файле main.cpp, но он работает именно в Xcode. Пробовал это сделать в онлайн компиляторе. И ничего не вышло. Вот и получается не могу понять, почему в Xcode это всё верно компилируется и линкуется.

Comment: «нет объявления функции f в файле main.cpp» — неправда, вы собственноручно добавили это объявление написав `#include"dop.cpp"`

Comment: То есть у нас эти два файла объединятся и получится один объектный файл? Или два объектных файла?

Comment: Вы в принципе не сможете скомпилировать dop.cpp, потому что компилятор будет ругаться на отсутствие iostream и на дубликат функции f (потому что функция f уже есть в файле main.cpp, потому что вы добавили её через #include"dop.cpp")